# How to get the current user address with no permission?

Tags: geolocation

I have been trying to get the current user with no permission. same as http://www.homedepot.com/

and I am using google API but I know it requires a permission

```
    window.onload = function() {
      var startPos;
      var geoOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }

      var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
      };
      var geoError = function(error) {
        console.log('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
        // error.code can be:
        //   0: unknown error
        //   1: permission denied
        //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
        //   3: timed out
      };

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);
    };
```

[image]
any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Google API geolocation, you will need to get a browser API key. Then, restrict it to a certain domain. After that, use the API key only in the domain. JavaScript will allow you to call requests.